# Clarification on integrity guarantees provided by UploadFromStreamAsync

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

When using UploadFromStreamAsync from the WindowsAzure.Storage nuget, for files both large and small, is there any scenario possible where you can end up with a corrupt file being committed to blob storage?  If not, how does it guarantee it?

I have noticed that when you use OpenWriteAsync that you can end up writing a corrupt file if an error occurs while writing to the stream.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-scalable-app-upload-files it is possible to end up with corrupted file. But in the example they set the `BlobRequestOptions` `DisableContentMD5Validation` value to `true`

It says in the docs, that if you set `DisableContentMD5Validation = true`

> This property disables checking the MD5 hash of the content uploaded.
>   Disabling MD5 validation produces a faster transfer. But does not
>   confirm the validity or integrity of the files being transferred.